# calling method of a web page without instantiating the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In my application we have an aspx page `frmwebform1`.
This page has a static method `GetmyData()` which calls a helper class `HelperClass`
But the problem with the code is that when we call the method `GetHelperData()`, in this
helper class it instantiates `frmwebform1` in order to get its method `FillGrid()`.
The problem is when it instantiates `frmwebform1` we are loosing `entityId` and `entityType` values.

Is there any way I could call the method `FillGrid()` without instantiating the `frmwebform1` page. Unfortunately I cannot make the `FillGrid()` method as static, as it 
will compromise our data.

Thanks for you help in advance.

```
//frmwebform1.aspx.cs
public partial class frmwebform1 : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    string entityId;
    string entityType;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
       if (Request.QueryString["entityId"] != null)
         {
           entityType = Request.QueryString["entityType"].ToString().ToUpper();
           entityId = Request.QueryString["entityId"].ToString();       
         }
       if (!IsPostBack)
         {
           grdMygrid.DataSource = FillGrid();
           grdMygrid.DataBind();
         }
    }
        public  DataTable FillGrid()
            {
                string server = HttpContext.Current.Session["Server"].ToString();
                string database = HttpContext.Current.Session["Database"].ToString();
                string usrID =HttpContext.Current.Session["user_ID"].ToString();
                Data tr = new getData(server, database, usrID);
                DataTable dt = tr.getAllEntities(entityId);

                return dt;
            }

        [WebMethod]      //AJAX page method
            public static List<class1> GetmyData()
            {
                HelperClass helper = new HelperClass();
                return helper.GetHelperData();
            }

 }

//Second Class

 public class HelperClass
    {
        public  List<class1> GetHelperData()
        {
            frmwebform1 form1 = new frmwebform1();
            DataTable dt = form1.FillGrid();

            List<class1> list = new List<class1>();
            class1 item;

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                item = new TaxHistory();
                item.txr_guid = dr["txr_guid"].ToString();                
                item.Amount = string.Format("{0}", dr["Amount"]);
                item.Email = dr["EmailAddress"].ToString();
                item.Date = dr["date"].ToString();
                item.user = dr["user"].ToString();                

                list.Add(item);
            }

            return list;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used PageMethods from Javascript. which solved my issue.
Thanks for all your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Extract that method from the Page class because it clearly should not be there as it seems to be of a different responsibility:

[How do we determine an object's responsibility in OOP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658629/how-do-we-determine-an-objects-responsibility-in-oop)

Create a static class and put that method there.

Answer (score 0):

Make the FillGrid method static.

Comment: Actually FillGrid method is static method. But due to some data compromise we changed this method to non static method.Apprceciate any other advise.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having method that fetches data from the db in page class and calling it from some  other class is not good thing. If you know layered architecture, you should move that method to Data Access Layer and call that method from page method, which will return you DataTable.

I hope it makes sense :)